# F1 Score metric per class in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I have implemented the following metric to look at Precision and Recall of the classes I deem relevant.

```
metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=1, name='Bkwd_R'),tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=2, name='Fwd_R'),tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=1, name='Bkwd_P'),tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=2, name='Fwd_P')]
```

How can I implement the same in Tensorflow 2.5 for F1 score (i.e specifically for class 1 and class 2, and not class 0, without a custom function.

---

**Update**

Using this metric setup:

```
tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes = 3, average = None, name = f1_name)
```

I get the following during training:

```
13367/13367 [==============================] 465s 34ms/step - loss: 0.1683 - f1_score: 0.5842 - val_loss: 0.0943 - val_f1_score: 0.3314
```

and when I do model.evaluate:

```
224/224 [==============================] - 11s 34ms/step - loss: 0.0665 - f1_score: 0.3325
```

and the scoring =

```
Score: [0.06653735041618347, array([0.99740255, 0.        , 0.        ], dtype=float32)]
```

The problem is that this is training based on the average, but I would like to train on the F1 score of a sensible averaging/each of the last two values/classes in the array (which are 0 in this case)

---

**Edit**

Will accept a non tensorflow specific function that gives the desired result (with full function and call during fit code) but was really hoping for something using the exisiting tensorflow code if it exists)

Comment: When you say 'I would like to train on the F1 score' do you mean you want to use your F1 score as a loss, not just as a metric (in your call to model.compile)? If you just want it as a metric, it should be possible to calculate it from your training history. If you want it to be your loss function, it's a bit more complex, since it's an aggregate function, not something that can be aggregated from individual examples in the way loss scores usually are. But I think it can be done, maybe not 'without a custom function' though.

Comment: I think I want it to be a loss function, here I am questioning my understanding on how the model trains. How is it that it still trains on loss but aims to better the metric? i.e if loss is what is being trained on, does that mean the metric I am using is just an indicator? so changing metric from accuracy to anything else like F1 or recall etc. makes no difference on the models training ability?

Comment: Yes, that's spot on. Training minimizes the loss. Metrics are just indicators, and do not influence the training. I recommend using the standard cross-entropy loss functions for training classification models - they have a long record of success. The answer by Bryan below is very good, I feel.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, my misunderstanding of that simple thing is hugely significant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is mentioned in David Harris' comment, **a neural network model is trained on loss functions, not on metric scores**. Losses help *drive* the model towards a solution to provide accurate labels via backpropagation. Metrics help to provide a comparable evaluation of that model's performance that are a lot more human-legible.

So, that being said, I feel like what you're saying in your question is that *"there are three classes, and I want the model to care more about the last two of the three"*. I want to

**IF** that's the case, one approach you can take is to **weight** your samples by label. Let's say that you have labels in an array `y_train`.

```py
# Which classes are you wanting to focus on
classes_i_care_about = [1, 2]
# Initialize all weights to 1.0
sample_weights = np.ones(shape=(len(y_train),))
# Give the classes you care about 50% more weight
sample_weight[np.isin(y_train, classes_i_care_about)] = 1.5

...

model.fit(
    x=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    sample_weight=sample_weight,
    epochs=5
)
```

This is the best advice I can offer without knowing more. If you're looking for other info on how you can have your model do better on certain classes, other info could be useful, such as:

- What's the proportions of labels in your dataset?
- What is the last layer of your model architecture? `Dense(3, activation="softmax")`?
- What loss are you using?

Here's a more complete, reproducible example that shows what I'm talking about with the sample weights:

```py
import numpy as np

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

iris_data = load_iris() # load the iris dataset

x = iris_data.data
y_ = iris_data.target.reshape(-1, 1) # Convert data to a single column

# One Hot encode the class labels
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
y = encoder.fit_transform(y_)

# Split the data for training and testing
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)

# Build the model
def get_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(4,), activation='relu', name='fc1'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', name='fc2'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='output'))

    # Adam optimizer with learning rate of 0.001
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(
        optimizer,
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=[
            'accuracy',
            tfa.metrics.F1Score(
                num_classes=3,
                average=None,
            )
        ]
    )
    return model

model = get_model()
model.fit(
    train_x,
    train_y,
    verbose=2,
    batch_size=5,
    epochs=25,
)

results = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)

print('Final test set loss: {:4f}'.format(results[0]))
print('Final test set accuracy: {:4f}'.format(results[1]))
print('Final test F1 scores: {}'.format(results[2]))
```

```
Final test set loss: 0.585964
Final test set accuracy: 0.633333
Final test F1 scores: [1.         0.15384616 0.6206897 ]
```

Now, we add weight to classes 1 and 2:

```py
sample_weight = np.ones(shape=(len(train_y),))
sample_weight[
    (train_y[:, 1] == 1) | (train_y[:, 2] == 1)
] = 1.5

model = get_model()
model.fit(
    train_x,
    train_y,
    sample_weight=sample_weight,
    verbose=2,
    batch_size=5,
    epochs=25,
)

results = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)

print('Final test set loss: {:4f}'.format(results[0]))
print('Final test set accuracy: {:4f}'.format(results[1]))
print('Final test F1 scores: {}'.format(results[2]))
```

```
Final test set loss: 0.437623
Final test set accuracy: 0.900000
Final test F1 scores: [1.        0.8571429 0.8571429]
```

Here, the model has emphasized learning these, and their respective performance is improved.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I need to take some time to ingest this and work with my code but I think this may get me in the right direction. Just a pre thought before I get really into it, what would happen if I gave the class I don't care for a weight of 0?

Comment: If you set their weight to zero, there would be no "course-correction" for the model for getting those samples wrong. This means you might as well not have those samples in the dataset at all. You can certainly down-weight them, but in my humble opinion, it's best to minimize meddling with the dark art of sample weighting. Keep the weight interventions small and minimal, and lean on (1) more training epochs, (2) more data, (3) maybe a learning rate scheduler to get you the rest of the way there.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for explaining. With regards to  the last bit: 1) this is just flat lining with overfitting. 2) I have a huge amount of data already. I can get more still. 3) I have this and it has helped. But mostly my problem is 1) and due to my misunderstanding of not training on the metric and it just being an indicator, I can only think to train on the metric via weighting which seems to be the only thing left to try? Unless there's something more I could do?

Comment: I have a follow up question here if you know how to assist on applying the weights to a generator fed model? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73515018/apply-weighting-to-generator-fed-model

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score in tensorflow-addons package.
Specifically, if you need a per-class score, you need to set the **average** param to **None**, or **macro**.

Comment: in that link I can label the f1score using name, but there is nothing about per class? ie class_id=1. What does "None" result in?