# sklearn.metrics classification_report at the end of each epoch using a generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, generator

I feed my train and validation data with the following generator

```
def sequence_generator(data_type):
    data_type = data_type.decode('ascii')
    sequence_folder = f"{model_attributes['sequences_path']}/{data_type}"
    for numpy_file in random.sample(os.listdir(sequence_folder),len(os.listdir(sequence_folder))):
        if numpy_file.endswith(".npz"):
            with np.load(f"{sequence_folder}/{numpy_file}") as numpy_data:
                sequences = numpy_data['x']
                labels = numpy_data['y']
                class_weight = {0: 1, 1: 2 ,2: 2}
                labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 3)
                sample_weights = np.ones(shape=(len(labels),))
                sample_weights[(labels[:, 1] == 1) | (labels[:, 2] == 1) ] = 2

                for X,y,sample_weight in random.sample(list(zip(sequences,labels,sample_weights)),len(sequences)):
                    yield X,y,sample_weight

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=sequence_generator,args= ['train'], output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32))# output_shapes = ((train_shape), (3,)))

train_dataset = train_dataset.cache().batch(BATCH).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=validation_dataset, callbacks=[tensorboard,checkpoint,earlystop,lr_callback])
```

I am trying to return a classification report using

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

for the validation data at the end of epoch (and maybe training data during the epoch?)

I've tried implementing it like so:

```
class class_report(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, val_data, batch_size = 32):
        super().__init__()
        self.validation_data = val_data
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        y_pred = self.model.predict(self.validation_data)


        report_dictionary = classification_report(self.y_true, y_pred, output_dict = True)


history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=validation_dataset,callbacks=[tensorboard,checkpoint,earlystop,lr_callback,class_report(validation_dataset)])
```

but come into a rabbithole of problems from what I understand is because y_true is within the generator tuple as a prefetch type and/or tensor?

current error:

```
AttributeError: 'class_report' object has no attribute 'y_true'
```

How can I properly implement this, even by an alternative method?

---

**Attempts:**

*I am not very good with imlpementing a `class` so I've kind of being stabbing in the dark*

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):

    print(self.validation_data)

    true_values = self.validation_data[:,1]

    y_pred = self.model.predict(self.validation_data)



........
............
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(64,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
       0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
       0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
       0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
       0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
      dtype=float32)>)
........
............
```

(0.5s due to class_weights 0.5x1)

```
  File "Train.py", line 2107, in build_and_train_model
    history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=validation_dataset,callbacks=[tensorboard,checkpoint,earlystop,lr_callback,class_report(validation_dataset)])
  File "Location\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1229, in fit
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "Location\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 435, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "Train.py", line 254, in on_epoch_end
    true_values = self.validation_data[:,1]
TypeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

---

```
true_values = list(self.validation_data)[:,1]



File "Train.py", line 254, in on_epoch_end
    true_values = list(self.validation_data)[:,1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

---

```
print(self.validation_data[1])


TypeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're encountering? `y_true is within the generator tuple as a prefetch type and/or tensor?` Depends on how you create the dataset, it could be a tensor or it could be an ndarray. In my experience, it's mostly ndarrays. A glaring problem I see from your code is that you're passing raw `y_pred` values to classification report, which will almost never match. `y_true` is going to be int values, or int-like (floats rounded to a whole number). `y_pred` will almost guaranteed to *not* be int-like.

Comment: If this is binary classification, you need to use `np.rint()` with `y_pred`. If it's multi-class classification, you need to use `np.argmax()` with `y_pred`.

Comment: I've added the errors I get based on the code shown and edited to show my attempts and the errors. It is multi-class, but my issue is that I cannot seperate the labels from the values in order to provide `y_true`. I suppose I would also then need to apply `np.argmax()` to the labels?

Comment: You can iterate through prefetched datasets. Have you tried the method `as_numpy_iterator()`? It should then just be something similar to `for image, label in dataset.as_numpy_iterator()` You might have to debug and look at the actual variable contents to see what to look for.